# Subsequence and subset of the array

Tags: subset, subsequence

I have a doubt between the subsequence and subset of the array.
Suppose I have an array:

**nums = [1,2,3]**

**output = [[],[1],[2],[1,2],[3],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]**

Whether output contains subsequence or subset of the nums ?

Subsequence means maintaing the relative order but may/may not be contigous. And subset means any combination of elements.

So I think we can say output conatins both subsequence and subset of nums ?

Can anyone help me in clarifying it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between subarray, subset & subsequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568560/difference-between-subarray-subset-subsequence)